# Visual editing of hypergraph(DB) data

Tags: user-interface, graph, hypergraph, hypergraphdb

Is it possible to visiually access / edit graphs with hyperedges / reification (e.g. HypergraphDB) via a GUI (preferrably web-based and OpenSource, like webVOWL)?

I tried too search, but no existing topics I found refer to hyperedges / reification capability of graph editors.